# How can I edit form data before setting a model property using Ember and ember-data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm relatively new to Ember and trying to figure out how I can process some data from a form input before saving it to an Ember model. (I'm using ember-data).

The field is a phone number, and I want to be able to strip out all non-numeric characters before saving, so that 555-555-5555 or (555) 555-5555 etc. all become 5555555555 when saved.

Were I in Rails I could just use a before_save callback, but what is the best way in Ember to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a computed property, documented here http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/

In your case the "real" property will be what is saved to the model, and you will bind the computed property in your template. When the computed property is is set you can remove non-numeric characters and set the "real" property.